# Inequality for the function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Recently I've come across the following task:

> Suppose $f(x)$ is defined and continuous on $[0, + \infty)$
>
> $f(x) > 0, f'(x) > 0 \ \forall \ x \in [0, + \infty)$
>
> $f(0) = e$
>
> $\forall \ x >0 \ f(x) > f'(x)$ Then
>
> A) $f(1) < e$
>
> B) $f(e) < e^e$
>
> C) $f(2e) < e^8$
>
> D) $f(e^2) < e^{e^2}$
>
> E) A-D are false

What I've done: assume $f(x) = e^x + e - 1$ then $f(0) = e$, $f'(x) = e^x < e^x + e - 1$, so this function satisfies all conditions hence A), B) and D) are false. But I have no idea, how to prove that C) is correct. What should I use? Something like MVT?

Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)<f(x)$ and $f(0)=e$ implies that $f(x)<e^{x+1}$ for positive values of $x$. I think that should be enough to figure out everything in the question.

Comment: Yes, really, why didn't I try solving the differential equation...Thanks a lot!